# problem in android webview

Tags: android, html, webview, meta-tags, viewport

i used below content in html page

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="  
   width=device-width,
   height =800px,
   user-scalable=no" />
</head>
<body>
<img border="0" src="./happy_holi.jpg" alt="Pulpit rock" height="400px"  
 width="300px">image1</img>
</body>
</html>
```

iam displaying it in web view.
my problem is, if i do changes for meta tag height and width property no changes is happening in web view. why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see some changes, you should change the img height property, or maybe your webview width and height. (maybe you should post  apart of xml file)

```
<img border="0" src="./happy_holi.jpg" alt="Pulpit rock" height="800px"    width="600px">image1</img>
```

The meta tag contain only informations for your bowser...

Comment: then what is the use of viewport ?

Comment: The presence of the Viewport META tag indicates that the markup document is optimized for mobile devices.
Have a look at this post: http://learnthemobileweb.com/tag/viewport/